# I want to export and average the trend line formulas of multiple lines in plot function?

Tags: plot, rstudio, trendline

I have been able to generate a plot of multiple lines based on the following data.

[image: Data sample]

This is the code snippet (I apologize but my code does not match the formatting for this post so I added the snippet as an image).

```
for(i in 1:1){
speedpath = file.path("C:",paste("yspeedplot_",format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %Hh%Mm%Ss"), ".png", sep = ""))
png(file=speedpath, width=(framewidthx*2), height=(frameheighty*2), units="px", bg = "white",res=300)

xrange=range(Timestamp_num)
yrange=range(boundy)
mytitle = paste("People Y-Speeds_",format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
plot(Timestamp_num, boundy, type="n", yaxt = "n",main=mytitle, xlab="Time Stamp", ylab="Y location",
   xlim=c(0,max_time),ylim=c(0,frameheighty))
axis(side = 2, at = yticks, labels = yticks)
colors=rainbow(number_people, alpha=colorsalp)
linetype=c(1:number_people)
plotchar = seq(18,18+number_people,1)

for (i in 1:length(unique(PersonID_Num))) {
lines(Timestamp_num[PersonID_Num==unique(PersonID_Num)[i]], 
      boundy[PersonID_Num==unique(PersonID_Num)[i]], type = "b", lwd = 1.5, lty = linetype[i], col = colors[i], pch=16)
}
dev.off()

}
```

Which produces the following plot for me.

[image: Speed plot]

I want to be able to export the trend line slope for each plot line. I then want to calculate the average trend line slope for all plot lines. How do I do this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example in your question, not as an image!

Comment: Hi Ralf I added the code snippet text. I apologize about that.

Comment: The code should be in the question, not in an answer. I have moved the code to the question and suggest you delete the „answer“.